# Finding the best matching block/patch in Python

Tags: python, arrays, window, patch, matching

I wish to locate the closest matching NxN block within a WxW window centred at location (x,y) of a larger 2D array. The code below works fine but is very slow for my needs as I need to run this operation many times. Is there a better way to do this?? 
Here N = 3, W = 15, x =15, y = 15 and (bestx,besty) is the centre of the best matching block

```
import numpy as np

## Generate some test data
CurPatch = np.random.randint(20, size=(3, 3))
Data = np.random.randint(20,size=(30,30))

# Current Location 
x,y = 15,15
# Initialise Best Match
bestcost = 999.0
bestx = 0;besty=0

for Wy in xrange(-7,8):
    for Wx in xrange(-7,8):
            Ywj,Ywi = y+Wy,x+Wx 

            cost = 0.0
            for py in xrange(3):
                for px in xrange(3):
                    cost += abs(Data[Ywj+py-1,Ywi+px-1] - CurPatch[py,px]) 

            if cost < bestcost:
                bestcost = cost
                besty,bestx = Ywj,Ywi

print besty,bestx
```

Comment: You can check if `cost` is bigger or equal to `bestcost` inside the `for px in xrange(3):` if so you can `break`, that way you can save a lot unnecessary iterations.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving working code, this question might be better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

As i said in the comment you can check if `cost` is bigger or equal to `bestcost` inside the `for px in xrange(3):` if so you can break, that way you can save a lot unnecessary iterations

Example (will a light alter to emphasize the difference on bigger iterations):

```
import numpy as np
import time

## Generate some test data
CurPatch = np.random.randint(100, size=(3, 3))
Data = np.random.randint(100, size=(3000,3000))

# Current Location 
x,y = 10, 10
# Initialise Best Match
bestcost = 999.0
bestx = 0;besty=0

t0 = time.time()
for Wy in xrange(-7,50):
    for Wx in xrange(-7,50):
            Ywj, Ywi = y+Wy, x+Wx

            cost = 0.0
            for py in xrange(3):
                for px in xrange(3):
                    cost += abs(Data[Ywj+py-1,Ywi+px-1] - CurPatch[py,px])
                    if cost >= bestcost:
                        break

            if cost < bestcost:
                bestcost = cost
                besty,bestx = Ywj,Ywi

print besty, bestx
print "time: {}".format(time.time() - t0)
```

Will time at 26ms

> time: 0.0269999504089

Your code with out the break will output 37ms:

> time: 0.0379998683929

Also i have to suggest to convert this code to a function.

Answer (score 0):

to get a feel for speed, the sub problem where w is the same size as you large window is faster(and briefer) using numpy:

```
a= '''import numpy as np


## Generate some test data
CurPatch = np.random.randint(20, size=(3, 3))
Data = np.random.randint(20,size=(30,30))


def best(CurPatch,Data):

    # Current Location 
    x,y = 15,15
    # Initialise Best Match
    bestcost = 999.0
    bestx = 0;besty=0

    for Wy in xrange(-14,14):
        for Wx in xrange(-14,14):
                Ywj,Ywi = y+Wy,x+Wx 

                cost = 0.0
                for py in xrange(3):
                    for px in xrange(3):
                        cost += (Data[Ywj+py-1,Ywi+px-1] - CurPatch[py,px])**2 

                if cost < bestcost:
                    bestcost = cost
                    besty,bestx = Ywj,Ywi
    return besty,bestx,bestcost



def minimize(CurPatch,W):
    max_sum=999
    s= CurPatch.shape[0]
    S= W.shape[0]
    for i in range(0,S-s):
        for j in range(0,S-s):
            running= np.sum(np.square((W[i:i+3,j:j+3]-CurPatch)))
            if running<max_sum:
                max_sum=running
                x=i+1;y=j+1
    return x,y,max_sum

'''


import timeit
print min(timeit.Timer('minimize(CurPatch,Data)', a).repeat(7, 10))
print min(timeit.Timer('best(CurPatch,Data)', a).repeat(7, 10))
```